# monologue gem with media plugin in tinemce

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, monologue

I am using [monologue](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue) gem to mount a blog in existing rails application. It is working fine. But i need to embed audio and video content in tineMCE. For that we need to add media plugin as mentioned [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3amedia). Initailly monologue only having "fullscreen" plugin. We can see that [here](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/monologue/admin/tinymce-config.js). How can i add media plugin to the existing monologue configurations. ?

Answer (score 0):

Search the monologue source code for the point where tinymce gets initiallized. `tinymce.init` or `mceAddControll` will be sufficient strings to search for.
when found you will find out if you are able to configure monologue to your needs or if you will have to hack the plugin list in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do i need to check this file? https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/monologue/admin/tinymce-config.js ? Can i able to configure this from my rails app?

Comment: this is the correct file, you will eighter have to put the mediaplugin into the plugin list there or overwrite the whole tinymce setting BEFORE the file gets evaluated by the browser. I am not familiar with rails, but it looks like you cannot to this.